# xcode how to display images in collection view cell from database

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, sqlite

I am just a beginner. i want to display image which is stored in database in a collection view cell. I have already created database and collection view. my code is as follow,

```
MyDatabase *data;
data=[MyDatabase new];
imagearray=[data OpenMyDatabase:@"SELECT pic_name FROM exterior" :@"pic_name"];
```

so my question is how can i display images ? let me know the way/code
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following code for display `UIImage` grid. Add `UICollectionView` for your `xib` file. Don't forget to set the `delegate` in collection.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
    {
        return  noOfItem/ noOfSection;
    }

    - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
         numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return noOfSection;
    }

    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                      cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
          static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = 
     [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier 
                                               forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:
                             (indexPath.section * noOfSection + indexPath.row)];

    return cell;


    }
```

In your xib file add UIImageView to your **CollectionViewCell** and change it **tag** value to 100.

Answer (score 2):

Please go through below links.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html

Above link is from Apple developer site. It has all details of UIcollectionview and tutorials related it. Below URL is also having sample tutorial, which will help you a lot.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

You have images array retrieved from database. Now it will act as data source for collection view. You need to form UICollectionViewCell which will have those images accordingly. Please study above links, you will get to know.

Comment: thanx mate, I have already created a UICollection view with custom view cell, just tel me the code to display image in that particular collection view. Code of collection view that i created is,      static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell" ;
    customcell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[cell nyimage]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];
    return cell;

Comment: Code will look like as Hansintha mentioned.